# Xcode Duplicate Target Won't Run

Tags: ios, xcode, target

There are plenty similar questions around, but none of the answers work in my case, so here we go again...

My Workspace has one (1) project, that project has one (1) target.

I decided to duplicate that target, so I can build a variation of my app (think lite version/paid version, but different).

Any scheme involving the duplicate target builds OK, but won't run. Specifically, on the simulator I get:

> **Cannot run on the selected destination**
>
> The selected destination does not support the architecture for which
>   the selected software is built.  Switch to a destination that supports
>   that architecture in order to run the selected software.

...and of course, on the device:

> **Xcode cannot run using the selected device.**
>
> Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on
>   this device.

**Notes**

1. Any scheme involving the original (old) target builds AND runs OK.
2. The product name contains **no_spaces**.
3. I tried every combination of 'Architectures' / 'Valid Architectures' / 'Build Active Architecture Only' etc. to no avail...
4. I am already deploying to 4.3 or greater, so I don't need/want armv6.
5. I am using Xcode 4.5, base SDK 6.0 so armv6 shouldn't be an option anyway.
6. When I try to install an AdHoc build through iTunes, I get error 0xE8008001
7. When I try to install an AdHoc build through Xcode Organizer, I get these three warnings:

**Validate Warning**
iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7 (-19033)

**Validate Warning**
Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

**Validate Warning** 
Unable to extract entitlements from application: (null) (-19045)

Any clue?

**UPDATE**

I tried creating a new target from scratch instead ("empty iOS application"), and adding all the classes/frameworks/resources one by one. Same error. Guess someone at Cupertino doesn't want you to reuse any code...

**UPDATE 2**

Just to see what happens, I changed the "Product Name" (under "Build Settings -> Packaging") of the ***original*** target (the one that runs), and now I get the same errors. To be clear: both the old and new Product Names are letters and underscores-only. **FIXED** this one was due to the Executable Name on the plist not matching the Product Name on build settings. Usually the plist contains a $() variable, but I had that field hard-coded...
Still, the duplicate target won't run...

**FIXED**

Now it's working... I think I wasn't cleaning the new target, only the old one. Thought 'clean' would clean everything, but the real time log view in the middle of Xcode's window shows different...

Comment: can you post linker logs in the question? you can get this by selecting last icon in the side bar and selecting "all messages" would show you all build logs

Comment: The original target finishes building with 18 errors (all pngcrush) but runs. The duplicated target finishes building with 26 errors (all pngcrush) and fails to run with the error messages mentioned above (although I get a green check in the linker logs navigator)

Comment: 18 down to 4 (in adding resources to targets, some psd's got added, files duplicated, etc.)

Comment: OK, eliminated al png related build errors, still no change...